# Implementing sequences of sequences in F#

Tags: interface, f#, types, overriding

I am trying to expose a 2 dimensional array as a sequence of sequences on an object(to be able to do `Seq.fold (fun x -> Seq.fold (fun ->..) [] x) []` mytype stuff specifically)

Below is a toy program that exposes the identical functionality.

From what I understand there is a lot going on here, first of `IEnumerable` has an ambiguous overload and requires a type annotation to explicitly isolate which `IEnumerable` you are talking about.

But then there can be issues with unit as well requiring additional help:

```
type blah =
class
    interface int seq seq with
        member self.GetEnumerator () : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(int*int)>> =
                seq{ for i = 0 to 10 do
                        yield seq { for j=0 to 10 do
                                        yield (i,j)} }
end
```

Is there some way of getting the above code to work as intended(return a `seq<seq<int>>`) or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: you would think someone learning FP would remember to check his type signatures....thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for one thing, `GetEnumerator()` is supposed to return `IEnumerator<T>` not `IEnumerable<T>`...

This will get your sample code to compile.

```
type blah =
    interface seq<seq<(int * int)>> with
        member self.GetEnumerator () =
            (seq { for i = 0 to 10 do
                    yield seq { for j=0 to 10 do
                                    yield (i,j)} }).GetEnumerator()
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
        member self.GetEnumerator () =
            (self :> seq<seq<(int * int)>>).GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let toSeqOfSeq (array:array<array<_>>) = array |> Seq.map (fun x -> x :> seq<_>)
```

But this works with an array of arrays, not a two-dimensional array. Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

What are you really out to do?  A seq of seqs is rarely useful.  All collections are seqs, so you can just use an array of arrays, a la

```
let myArrayOfArrays = [|
    for i = 0 to 9 do
        yield [|
            for j = 0 to 9 do
                yield (i,j)
            |]
    |]

let sumAllProds = myArrayOfArrays |> Seq.fold (fun st a ->
                             st + (a |> Seq.fold (fun st (x,y) -> st + x*y) 0) ) 0
printfn "%d" sumAllProds
```

if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
   module Array2D =
      // Converts 2D array 'T[,] into seq<seq<'T>>  
      let toSeq (arr : 'T [,]) =
         let f1,f2 = Array2D.base1 arr , Array2D.base2 arr
         let t1,t2 = Array2D.length1 arr - f1 - 1 , Array2D.length2 arr - f2 - 1
         seq {
           for i in f1 .. t1 do
              yield seq {
                 for j in f2 .. t2 do
                    yield Array2D.get arr i j }}

    let myArray2D : string[,] = array2D [["a1"; "b1"; "c1"]; ["a2"; "b2"; "c2"]]

    printf "%A" (Array2D.toSeq myArray2D)
```